# Perovskite characterization

Tags: chromatography, adsorption

Does anyone know of groups working on water sorbtion testing and/or the use of inverse gas chromatography for characterizing Perovskites (as a class of materials)? Especially with regard to applications eg solar PV

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Comment: When you say groups working on this material, do you mean research facilities?

Comment: Yes, either academic or industry